# Problema con Fpdf en yii 2

Tags: php, yii2, fpdf

Hola tengo este problema con el fpdf. al momento de generar el archivo me lanza esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En lugar del simple hola mundo que pido,
Aqui mi funcion del controlador, la funcion es actionGenerar:

```html
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Reportes;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\web\Controller;
use rudissaar\fpdf\FPDF;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use app\models\RegistroAdq;
use app\models\Adq;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * ReportesController implements the CRUD actions for Reportes model.
 */
class ReportesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Reportes models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Reportes::find(),
        ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }


    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Reportes::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }

    public function actionGenerar()
    {
            //$fecha_ini=$_POST['fecha_inicio'];
            //$fecha_fin=$_POST['fecha_fin'];
            //
            //$radq=RegistroAdq::find()
            //->where(['between', 'radq_fecha', $fecha_ini, $fecha_fin])
            //->all();
            //
            //foreach ($radq as $dato) {
            //$id=$dato->radq_adq;
            //}

        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
        $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Hello World');
        $pdf->Output('I');
    }

}
```

como ven es un simple hola mundo, nomas para hacerlo funcionar y posteriormente hacer mi pdf completo. ya e elaborado varios pero este es el primero que hago en yii2, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Intenta sin la I, `$pdf->Output()`

Comment: sale lo mismo :(, pero si pongo D para descargarlo si funciona y lo abro con adobe reader sale todo correctaente. solo no funciona si el navegador lo intenta abrir. uso firefox ultima version y este error solo me sale con yii 2.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer la página no sabe como interpretar el código que intentas imprimir, prueba agregando cabeceras de tipo PDF a tu método:

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf");
```

Tu método quedaría así:

```
public function actionGenerar()
    {
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf");

        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
        $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Hello World');
        $pdf->Output('I');
    }
```

Comment: lo mismo tambien :(. no se si ya sera de algun otro archivo de yii2 . lo que pasa es que no tiene mucho que empece a usar yii 2 y nomas porque así lo pide mi universidad. el que normalmente uso yo es codeigniter y nunca me salio este problema con los pdf que e elaborado

Answer (score 1):

despues de tanto buscar esta es la respuesta para que lo cargue en el controlador

```
Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
Yii::$app->response->headers->add("Content-Type', 'application/pdf");

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont("Arial", "B", 15);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, "Hello World");
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Para solucionar la excepción siguiente:      `Exception 'ArgumentCountError' with message 'Too few arguments to function yii\web\HeaderCollection::add(), 1 passed in'...`        Será necesario reemplazar la segunda línea por : `Yii::$app->response->headers->add('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');`                De lo contrario se interpreta como un parámetro en lugar de dos.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta dejando en blanco tu layout

```
public function actionGenerar()
{
        //$fecha_ini=$_POST['fecha_inicio'];
        //$fecha_fin=$_POST['fecha_fin'];
        //
        //$radq=RegistroAdq::find()
        //->where(['between', 'radq_fecha', $fecha_ini, $fecha_fin])
        //->all();
        //
        //foreach ($radq as $dato) {
        //$id=$dato->radq_adq;
        //}
    $this->layout = false;
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Hello World');
    $pdf->Output('I');
}
```

Comment: sigue apareciendo lo mismo :(

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que son los permisos de directorios, lo solucione creando un directorio publico con permisos de escritura del sistema.

```
//

use inquid\pdf\FPDF;


$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);

$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World! 2');

$pdf->Output('F',dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../pdf/hola.pdf');


///
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que son los permisos de directorios, lo solucione creando un directorio publico con permisos de escritura del sistema.

```
use inquid\pdf\FPDF;


$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);

$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World! 2');

$pdf->Output('F',dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../pdf/hola.pdf');
```

Actualizacion de mi anterior respuesta:

```
$pdf->Output('F',dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../pdf/hola.pdf');
$pdf->Output($file,$url_con_permisode_escritura);
```